# Prove that ..., f(x-2), f(x-1), f(x), f(x+1), f(x+2),... is algebraically linearly independent without the Fourier transform

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Suppose that $f$ is in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and consider the set of integer translates of this function, $V=\{f(x-k):k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$.  This set is linearly independent: taking the Fourier transform of the finite sum $\sum a_k f(x-k)$ one gets $p(e^{2\pi i\xi})\widehat{f}(\xi)$ for some polynomial $p$.  If the sum is zero and $f$ is nonzero, then $p$ must be zero on some set of positive measure; this is an infinite set, implying that $p$ must be the zero polynomial and so each $a_k$ must be zero.  I find this to be an especially nice application of the Fourier transform.

My question is this: does there exist a proof of this fact which does not use the Fourier transform?  The $L^2$ condition could be modified, but obviously one needs some kind of integrability condition to disallow the constant functions.  One can prove this using a variant of the Fourier transform, so I should say that I'm really looking for a proof where you don't integrate against complex exponentials.

As for why $V$ would be an interesting thing for mathematicians to look at: the closure of the span of $V$ (in $L^2$) is one of the fundamental objects in wavelet theory --- a principal shift-invariant space.

Comment: That set is not linearly independent (what if $f$ is odd?). Perhaps you meant that there is an infinite subset of $V$ that is linearly independent?

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure I can build a function $f\in L^2$ that is equal to 1 on every integer. You just need to make the spikes narrower and narrower as you get to infinity. That function would not be in $H^1$, of course, but that's another story.

Comment: Bartgol, he's talking about the functions $f(x-k) \in L^2,$ not the values of $f$ at the integers which wouldn't be well defined anyway.

Comment: Oh, of course. I read the question a little too fast. Silly me. =P

Comment: I wonder if anything could be done with the bi-infinite sequence $\langle a \rangle$ defined by $a_i=\sqrt{\int_i^{i+1}f^2(x)dx}$  so $|| f ||=\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}a_i^2.$ Dependence of shifts of $f$ do not correspond to dependence of shifts of $\langle a \rangle$ (i.e. a linear recurrence) but maybe some inequality can be brough to bear.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Suppose there is some linear dependence. If the set is linearly dependent, space $V$ should be finite dimensional.
Fix a finite subset $S$ of $\mathbb{Z}$ so that supposedly the set of $f(x-k)$ where $k\in S$ would span.

Note that as $k_0 \rightarrow \infty,$  $\langle f(x-k_0), f(x-k) \rangle \rightarrow 0,$ which would imply $\|f(x-k_0)\|$ went to $0,$ but $\|f(x-k_0)\|$ is constant, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm just being dense, but why does linear dependence imply the space is finite dimensional?  Certainly if you have one dependence relation, you will have infinitely many, but it doesn't seem obvious at first glance that I should get a finite dimensional space.

Comment: Well suppose you had a linear dependence, i.e. there $\sum^n_{k=-l} a_kf(x-k) =0,$ where $a_{-l}$ and $a_n$ are non-zero. By applying the shift, we get that $\sum^n_{k=-l} a_kf(x-(k+t)) =0.$ That is, for any $m > n$ or $m< -l$ we can write $f(m)$ in terms of a recurrence relation.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write $f(x-m).$

Comment: @Pascoe: I agree that that inner product goes to 0, but I don't see why that would imply the norm of $||f(x-k_0)||$ goes to 0 too. It's like trying to get strong convergence from weak convergence...

Comment: I guess the simplest answer would be that the function $\|v\|_S = (\sum_{k\in S} \langle v,f(x-k) \rangle^{2})^{1/2}$ defines a norm on $V$ which is finite dimensional, and all norms on a finite dimensional space are equivalent in the sense that they induce the same topology.

Comment: Uh, yeah. I forgot you just proved the space is finite dimensional.

Comment: Well, $f(x)=\cos(x)$ certainly would give linearly dependent $f(x+\alpha)$. So the assumptions needed to apply Fourier transform are relevant.

Comment: $\cos x$ isn't in $L^2.$

Comment: Sorry, just glossed over that requirement in the problem setting.

Comment: Instead of changing the norm, I think it's probably nicer to say you know the space of translates is finite-dimensional, so pick a (finite) orthogonal basis. By the condition in this answer, the inner product with any basis element goes to 0. Hence the strong norm (of $f(x-k)$) goes to 0 as $k\to\infty$.

Comment: I'm embarrassed I didn't make that observation myself about the finite dimensionality of $V$.  It's a nice little argument.  It also highlights that the $2$ in the $L^2$ condition isn't key as you wind up in a finite dimensional setting.  Showing that the inner product, $\langle f(x-k_0), f(x-k)\rangle$, tends to zero is equivalent to proving the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma, but if you just approximate $f$ with a $C_c^\infty$ function, I think all you need is the dominated convergence theorem and Cauchy-Schwarz, so trigonometric polynomials never enter the picture.  Thanks!